# Check-boxes with Radio-buttons quality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I need check-boxes list that has one quality of radio-buttons:

That you can check only one of them.

I don't want to use radio-buttons, becouse I need other qualities of check-boxes, like that you can un-check it by additional click.

Is there any simple way to do it?

I can use javascript, including knockout and jquery libraries.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a code snippet you're struggling with?

Comment: Once a checkbox is checked, disable the other checkboxes. Then when the one is unchecked, then remove the disable attr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/ecp7xxqm/4/)

```
$(function() {
    $(':checkbox').on('change',function() {
        $(':checkbox[name=' + this.name + ']:checked').not(this).prop('checked',false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Group1</legend>
       <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />
       <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />
       <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />
  </fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Group2</legend>
       <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />
       <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />
       <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />
</fieldset>
```

> Checkbox Group exactly like a radio button group

**jsfiddle:**
[Checkbox Group](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/2yw3bj7k/1/)

**Javascript:**

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']";
    $(group).attr("checked",false);
    $(this).attr("checked",true);
});
```

> Checkbox Group you can remove all checked.

jsfiddle:
[Checkbox Group(can remove all checked)](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/sL4sqjp1/1/)

**Javascript:**

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']";    
    $(group).not(this).prop("checked",false);
    $(this).prop("checked",!this.checked);      
});
```

Comment: close, but OP also said `need other qualities of check-boxes, like that you can un-check it by additional click`. Your example does not allow for unchecking the checkbox.

Comment: I've updated the answer.
It may be useful to others.